# How to get the rightmost digit from an Integer - Ruby

Tags: ruby, integer, digit

I am working on a program that requires me to read in and validate a number, but in doing so I need to take a two digit integer (for example we'll say 18) and add it 1 + 8. Now I have it working where I do a conditional check if it is greater than 10 and subtract, but that's kind of an ugly solution in my opinion and was wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to read in a string representation of a number and compute the sum of the last two digits of that number?  If so, is it guaranteed that the number has at least two digits?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `n % 10`, to get the rightmost digit. For example:

```
18 % 10
# => 8 
9 % 10
# => 9 
0 % 10
# => 0
(-123).abs % 10
# => 3
```

To handle negative numbers, use [Integer#abs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-abs).

**EDIT**

Ruby 2.4 has a [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) method. It will give you the digits as an array, starting from unit's place. And if you want to add the digits, you can use [Enumerable#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum).

```
123.digits
# =>[3, 2, 1]

123.digits.first
# => 3

123.digits.sum
# => 6
```

Answer (score 1):

To add all digits from a number, you can use the following:

```
18.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

It transforms the number into a string, splits it into digits, transforms each into an integer and adds them all together.

Works with numbers of any length.

Comment: You might want to use `.chars` instead of `.split('')`

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
int = 10000023
int.digits.first(2).sum
# => 5
```

`int.digits`: This method returns an array of digits of the integer `int`, starting from the least significant digit to the most significant one.
`first(n)`: This method is chained to digits and retrieves the first `n` elements from the array of digits, which are the last two digits of the integer.
`sum`: This method calculates the sum of all elements in the array returned by `digits.first(2)`. In this case, it calculates the sum of the first two digits of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
any_number = 1234

# Ensure your input is at most a two digit number (might not be needed)
two_digit_number = any_number % 100                    #=> 34

# Calculate the final addition
total = two_digit_number / 10 + two_digit_number % 10  #=> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

For two digit integers, there is at least another method we could use: `Numeric#divmod`, which returns the quotient and modulus in an array. And here's a look at the speed of the different approaches to sum up the digits:

```
b = 18
n = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('to_s:') { n.times { b.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) }}
  x.report('divmod:') { n.times { b.divmod(10).reduce(:+) }}
  x.report('direct division:') { n.times { b/10 + b%10 } }
  x.report('digits:') { n.times { a.digits.reduce(:+) } }
end

#####
                       user     system      total        real
to_s:              0.750000   0.000000   0.750000 (  0.750700)
divmod:            0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.153516)
direct division:   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.076697)
digits:            0.560000   0.020000   0.580000 (  0.574687)
```

Comment: I ran this benchmark with `ruby-2.6.0` and I get very different results, at least for the `digits` method. Also why the variable used in digits method is `a` instead of `b` thats used with every other method?

Answer (score 0):

Here a hands on solution for the fun of it:

```
def get_digits(n)

  res=[]; i=0;

  while 10**i < n
    res.push( n/10**i%10 )
    i += 1
  end

  return res

end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def  digits_sum(number,n)
  number_array=number.to_s.chars  
  n=[n,number_array.length].min
  number_array.slice(-n,n).map {|c| c.to_i }.reduce(:+) || 0
end
```

this method return the sum of N right-digits.

```
digits_sum 123456789,5 => 35
digits_sum 123456789,2 => 17
```

This will work if you give N greater then number length but wont work if negative count is provided